# Dynamic image height and width in html emails in Outlook

Tags: reactjs, outlook, html-email

I am sending an HTML email with the content generated by React.js.  In the body of the email I have to put the client's icon in a 40x40 cell.

Some client's icons are square and they look fine.  Others are tall or wide and Outlook is distorting them to fit in the 40x40 cell, which is not cool.

Here are a few things I have tried, and how Outlook ruins them:

1. **Shows the image in its full size (max-height and max-width are not working):**

```html
<table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="40" height="40">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img
          alt=""
          border="0"
          src={iconUrl}
          width="auto"
          height="auto"
          style={{ display: "block", maxHeight: "40px", maxWidth: "40px" }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2. **Distorts the image making it a 40x40 square:**

```html
<table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="40" height="40">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img
          alt=""
          border="0"
          src={iconUrl}
          width="40"
          height="40"
          style={{ display: "block", width: "auto", height: "auto", maxHeight: "40px", maxWidth: "40px" }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

3. **Shows the image in its full size:**

```html
<table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="40" height="40">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img
          alt=""
          border="0"
          src={iconUrl}
          style={{ display: "block", maxHeight: "40px", maxWidth: "40px" }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

4. **Outlook does not support any `background` style properties, so nothing appears**:

```html
<table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="40" height="40">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div
          style={{
            display: "block",
            height: "40px",
            width: "40px",
            backgroundImage: `url(${iconUrl})`,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            backgroundPosition: "center center",
          }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

5. **Shows the image in its full size:**

```html
<table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="40" height="40">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img
          alt=""
          border="0"
          src={iconUrl}
          style={{ display: "block", maxWidth: "40px", maxHeight: "40px", objectFit: "cover" }}
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Outlook will ignore image widths set in the inline style. Since your icons are supposed to be 40px, declare the width as `<img width="40" />`

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="40">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" width="40" height="40" alt="" border="0"  style="height: auto; max-width: 40px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In addition, Outlook only does background images using VML.

Finally, Outlook and other email clients will ignore HTML and CSS that is not formatted in the correct manner. I would suggest brushing up on the correct way to separate css values `;`. You will experience less headaches.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The logo could be 100x20, in which case I’d want it to appear as 40x8. Or the logo could be 20x100, in which case I’d want it to appear as 8x40. Your solution always shows it as a 40x40 square, which is incorrect. Also the css with commas instead of semicolons is because it is React.

Comment: The inline style width point gwally makes is totally incorrect. I personally prefer to use style widths as opposed to inline attribute declarations and have never had an issue. Unless it comes to 120% DPI views of Outlook, that is when I include both.

Comment: @AlanP. You can use the inline style to dynamically set the width for every email client that understands that. With Outlook 2007-2019, you need to set the width in the image. Try it and you'll figure it out.